# <a target = "name" .......> tag is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

We have a JSP page here I used HTML and Java Script. I am having multiple links and I used `<a>` and `window.open()` tag for hyperlinks.

1. After clicking on the link, it should open a new browser window.
2. After the second click the application should display the relevant text in the already opened new browser window(the window openened in step 1 above).
3. This is then true for all further window clicks.

There should be only at the max two browser windows open on the user's computer.
My current code is working fine for all browser expect internet explorer. I am attaching code sample. This working fine in Chrome but not in IE:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="infoWindow">link1</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="infoWindow">link2</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="infoWindow">link3</a>
```

Comment: You should provide the IE version you are having problems with. Also I see no `target=name` in your code, and `window.open()` is not a tag.

Comment: Hi Migg, I have tried with window.open() as well ... getting same issue

Comment: IE 11 i am checking with .

Comment: Tried code is window.open( "https://www.google.com" ,"myfm")